# In my 'high scores' python program, a comparison operator raises an error, but only sometimes

Tags: python, python-3.x

The question refers to the following python program -

```
# High Scores
# Maintains a list of the five highest scores and the players responsible.

hiscores = [56,45,23,11]
again = "a"


def findplace(xlist, x):
    # list is in descending order
    for j in range(len(xlist)-1):
        if x >= xlist[j]:
            xlist.insert(j, x)
            return xlist


while again:
    print("\n", hiscores)
    score = int(input("\nEnter a score (zero to exit): "))
    if score >= hiscores[3]:
        hiscores = findplace(hiscores, score)
    elif score == 0:
        again = ""


print(hiscores)
input("\nETE")
```

The program takes scores from the user and adds them to the list if they are high enough. I wanted to set the entry level at the lowest score by setting the index value on the third line of the while loop at 3, but this raises an error. 0, 1 and 2 work perfectly! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error does it raise?

Comment: I'd note that nothing here truncates or otherwise controls the length of the scores list, so this is going to store more than 5 scores as long as they are all higher than the 4th score in the list at insertion time...

Comment: If you add a score of 11 or above the output on the next line is None. Any further value raises 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable' in reference to the line in question. But with the values below 3 this doesn't happen. Also, I know the list is not limited, the program is unfinished.

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your problem with the "entry level" score. However, since your list has only five elements anyway, you can make things easier by dropping the entry level check completely.

```
while True:
    print("\n", hiscores)
    score = int(input("\nEnter a score (zero to exit): "))
    if score == 0:
        break
    hiscores = findplace(hiscores, score)
```

Also note that your `findplace` method will extend the high scores list to more than five entries, and that it can return `None` if the score is not within the first `len-1` entries. Instead, you could just add the new score, sort the list in reverse order, and take the first five elements.

```
def findplace(xlist, x):
    return sorted(xlist + [x], reverse=True)[:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `findplace` only returns a new list if the score is a high score. If you enter `11`, which is not inserted, it doesn't hit a `return` statement (and so returns `None`). Since you set `highscores = findplace(hiscores, score)`, you essentially set your list to `None`, causing the `TypeError`.

Moving `return xlist` to the same level as the `for` loop in `findplace` fixes this error (but reveals a logic error in your `findplace` function, which I'll leave for you to discover).

Comment: Thanks all, findplace didn't hit a return statement because of the -1 in the For loop. Range automatically goes to one less than the length, it doesn't have to be coded explicitly. The None was the clue.